# How do I change a susy parameter based on the number of items in an array?

Tags: sass, susy

I have an ng-repeat in an angular app that could have anywhere between 2 to 5 items and a 20 column susy grid. I want the items to total the full width of the grid so if there are 2 I want:

```
   .card:nth-child(1) {
    @include span(10 of 20);  }
    .card:nth-child(2) {
    @include span(10 of 20 last);  }
```

and if I have 5 cards I want:

```
   .card:nth-child(n+1):nth-child(-n+4) {
     @include span(4 of 20);  }
    .card:nth-child(5) {
    @include span(4 of 20 last);  }
```

And I need it to work for anything dynamically in between. 
Any idea how I can get something like this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, since Sass is a preprocessor and won't have knowledge of the DOM.